# Is it possible to change or modify built-in VBA editor in Excel for Mac 2011

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2011

I am using the built-in VBA editor in Excel 2011 for Mac, but the built-in editor doesn't respond well to my scrolling gestures. I'm having too much trouble writing/finding code.

Is it possible to change the editor with something else?

Answer (score 1):

It's always possible to edit code in another program and copy and paste back and forth.

BBEdit and VIM have Visual Basic modes that will format the code similar to Microsoft's built-in editor. Other do as well, see link below.

[Relavent Discussion of Editors](http://talk.tidbits.com/Best-Mac-Editor-for-VBA-td4659654.html)